# Is there a word for "more experienced colleague?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "more experienced colleague?" In particular, they have the same rank, but more experience on the job.

Edit: Thanks for the answers! I was wondering, is there a word like senior except with this connotation (like "my senior," except "my more experienced colleague?")

Comment: Sounds *senior*.

Comment: Senior is relevant but is often of senior rank, or merely older. The word does not necessarily imply greater experience.

Answer (score 1):

**An old hand** (n.): (OED) 1. A person who has been employed for a long time or who has experience in a business, or who is skilful in doing something.
*An old hand at photography, Tim has been shooting wildlife as a hobby for the last 13 years.* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/old-hand

Comment: Tim can be an old hand at photography without being anybody's colleague, though.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, but a good answer is hard to give when the OP fails to give an example sentence or context. you may agree that  context could do the job of establishing the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context, you might use

Mentor =

> a person who gives a younger or less experienced person help and advice over a period of time, especially at work or school
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mentor)

A mentor is not necessarily of the same rank but the definition includes those people who are so.

Comment: A mentor is someone who offers support and guidance: I don't think it fits with the OP's question.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, too. Depending on context, it might be a good replacement.

Comment: @Greybeard Mentor may only fit in part, as I point out in my answer. It also fits completely in the context of a mentor of equal rank.

Comment: @Greybeard I agree that it doesn’t totally fit based only on what’s said, but it’s not necessarily wrong. It just depends on what relationship they have, which isn’t described here :)

Comment: Greybeard's point was that *mentor* is defined in terms of what a mentor **does**, while the OP is looking for a word for somebody who has a certain status, regardless of what that person does or doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

The first definition of veteran in the Oxford dictionary is "a person who has had long experience in a particular field"

Answer (score 0):

**better** - One's superior in some personal quality or attainment or (now only in pl.) in social status.

**superior** - A person of superior rank or status.

**senior** - A person of (comparatively) advanced age, high standing, or long service.

**higher-up** - A superior.

[source - SOED]

Comment: The person who asked specifically said they have the same rank. All of these options denote higher rank.

Comment: @TomResing And I specifically looked for words that might be used to convey the having of more experience. Those definitions clearly allow for such usage. One can **attain** more experience. One can be **superior** in the **status** of their experience. One can be **advanced** in their **length of service.** The possibilities are shown right there in the definitions. Those terms absolutely *do not* denote higher rank. They are not proper names and their meaning can *only* be determined in a given context.

Answer (score 0):

**Expert** works well. For example: If Sarah has just been hired, her co-workers might say, “Go talk to Brian. He’s the **expert**.”